# How to compare the values of a row in a data frame with multiple rows from another data frame (include calculation)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Sorry for bad English for writing the title. What I would like to do is to determine the location of `df` by comparing with another data frame `df2`.
`df` is a data frame that shows the variation of longitude and latitude in a period of time. It is a data frame with more than 40,000 of rows.

```
    df=
                        Longitude Latitude     
        Time               
        2020-01-01 01:00    100.0   20.0       
        2020-01-01 01:01    100.2   20.1       
        2020-01-01 01:02    300.1   30.0       
        2020-01-01 01:03    200.1   40.0     
        2020-01-01 01:04     50.0   50.0
```

`df2` is the dataframe that contain the location data. It is a data frame with around 30 rows.

```
df2=
        Longitude Latitude   Location
    0        90.0   20.0     District A 
    1       210.0   60.0     District B
```

The method to determine where I am located will be done by Pythagoras theorem. Each row of data in `df` will compare with every row in `df2` to find the shortest distance, which the shortest distance is where I am located.

Take `2020-01-01 01:01` as an example.

First, compare with `df2 row 0`, the calculation is `[(100.2-90.0)^2+(20.1-20.0)^2]^0.5`.

Second, compare with `df2 row 1`, the calculation is `[(100.2-210.0)^2+(20.1-60.0)^2]^0.5`

Since the distance between the location and `District A` is smaller than the distance between the location and `District B`, therefore the location on `2020-01-01 01:01` will be `District A`. The expected output is given as follows.

```
df=
                            Longitude Latitude  Location   
            Time               
            2020-01-01 01:00    100.0   20.0    District A   
            2020-01-01 01:01    100.2   20.1    District A   
            2020-01-01 01:02    300.1   30.0    District B   
            2020-01-01 01:03    200.1   40.0    District B 
            2020-01-01 01:04     50.0   50.0    District A
```

My approach: To get my expected result first I will create a `df['Loaction']` column full of `NaN`, then I will do the calculation and extract the `df2['Location']` to substitute the `NaN` value in `df['Loaction']`.

However, what I am confused about is how to get the calculation results. Are there any related pandas function or NumPy function that can compare a row from `df` with multiple rows from `df2`? Is there a better approach? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am ignoring the time column since no operation is required.

```
d = {'Longitude': [100.0,100.2,300.1,200.1,50.0], 'Latitude': [20.0 , 20.1,30.0,40.0, 50.0 ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d2 = {'Longitude':[90.0, 210.0], 'Latitude':[20.0, 60.0], 'Location':['District A', 'District B']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

A lambda function may be applied row wise on df since we are comparing each row of df with all the rows of df2. It is not a one-to-one mapping.

So, at first I try to find the minimum distance and then get the 'Location' value from df2. Note that I have avoided the taking the sqrt value in the distance calculation to simplify solution. It should not matter anyway since only the minimum is required.

```
df.apply(lambda x: df2['Location'][(x[0] - df2['Longitude'])**2 + (x[1] - df2['Latitude'])**2 == min((x[0] - df2['Longitude'])**2 + (x[1] - df2['Latitude'])**2)].iloc[0], axis=1)
```

This should produce the following output.

```
df.apply(lambda x: df2['Location'][(x[0] - df2['Longitude'])**2 + (x[1] - df2['Latitude'])**2 == min((x[0] - df2['Longitude'])**2 + (x[1] - df2['Latitude'])**2)].iloc[0], axis=1)
0    District A
1    District A
2    District B
3    District B
4    District A
dtype: object
```

If you add the final column to df, then it looks as follows.

```
>>> df['Location'] = df.apply(lambda x: df2['Location'][(x[0] - df2['Longitude'])**2 + (x[1] - df2['Latitude'])**2 == min((x[0] - df2['Longitude'])**2 + (x[1] - df2['Latitude'])**2)].iloc[0], axis=1)
>>> 
>>> df
   Longitude  Latitude    Location
0      100.0      20.0  District A
1      100.2      20.1  District A
2      300.1      30.0  District B
3      200.1      40.0  District B
4       50.0      50.0  District A
```

Comment: If the solution is satisfactory, also please accept the answer as correct. It is the tick mark below the upvote button.

Comment: I have tried your example it works perfectly. But when I apply to my code it gives an error: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. All the df['Location'] is changed to 'District A'. I have researched for a while but I don't understand how lambda is not working due to my df is a copy

Comment: I am afraid, I would need more details such as the code you have written. However, this seems like a selection is performed on a data frame which has returned a copy and then when we try to set on this copy, the error is returned. Did you check this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: Also, if the answer solved the question posted, please accept the answer as correct.